# UICollectionView in UITabBar display wrong position on first load

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uitabbar

I have been stuck at this for days. The problem is that the collection view that is in a tab bar after its first load. It will be display incorrectly. If I press any tab the problem will disappear forever until the app is restarted. Note that it's not just a white space that appearing. The whole container is getting shift down so the white space appear.

**This problem only seem to exists on the iPhone and not the simulator. Tried it with iPhone 4 and 5.**

**After a second try I think it only happens in iOS 7 and not iOS 8**

**Can confirm that it only happens on iOS 7. Upgraded one iPhone 5 to iOS 8 and the bug is gone while another iPhone 5 is still iOS 7 and the problem appears every time.**

See the white space below?
[image: White space]

It disappear after I press another tab
[image: Disappear]

It doesn't even come back if I go back to the original one
[image]

I uploaded an example project with this problem here: https://github.com/athiwatc/UITabBarDisplayWrongPosition

Comment: I have run your code in xcode6 it is working fine.

Comment: @RameshMuthe I have Version 6.1 (6A1052d) and ran it in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 both have this problem. The simulator doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Yes, tried with the iPhone 4. This problem seem to only exists in real iPhone and not the simulator.

Comment: It works fine in iPhone 4s, no white space in initial load but only black space.

Comment: @gabbler This problem now seem very inconsistent. Guess I will try to upgrade my iPhone 5 to 8.1 from 7 to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: @gabbler Any chance that your iPhone 4s is iOS 8? Cause that would confirm what I have found.

Comment: yes,it is 8.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constraints as in the following screen shot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That is already set in the example project, still it doesn't work.

Comment: 128, but I tried others. Nothing works sadly. It seem to only happen in real devices only also.